# Has no exported member

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I am new in Typescript. I am using express js and I have the folowing problem. When I run the server it appear '...../routes.ts' has no exported member 'router'. I ve been searching but I didnt succeed. These are my files.

In my src/index.ts

```
import "reflect-metadata"
import * as express from "express"
import { router } from "./routes"

async function main() {
 const app = express()
 app.get('/api',router)
 app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server running"))
}

main()
```

In my src/routes.ts

```
import * as express from "express";
var router = express.Router();

router.route('/user').get((req, res) => res.send("Hello world"));

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a Typescript issue, you aren't exporting `router` as a named export so the `{ ... }` syntax won't work.

Given it appears to be the default export, you can use

```
import router from './routes.js'
```

Alternatively, if you are using a transpiler that supports the `export` syntax, you could export your router as a named export i.e.

```
export const router
```

This would allow you to import via `{ router }`.