# Error TS2305: Module "MyClass" has no exported member 'MyClass'

Tags: typescript

I'm getting the error when trying to:

```
export default class MyClass {
   private running: boolean = false;

   isRunning(): boolean {
       return true;
   }

   start():void {
       this.running = true;
   }

   stop():void {
       this.running = false;
   }
}
```

Error:

> Error TS2305: Module "MyClass" has no exported member 'MyClass'

main.ts:

```
import { MyClass } from "./MyClass";
import { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } from 'electron';


var myClass: MyClass = new MyClass();
console.log("Start:" + myClass.start());
```

**Update:**

This may be because I'm not transcoding typescript before launching my Electron project.

Comment: If my memory serves me right, because your using `export default class` when you import it you don't need to use the curly braces. Your import becomes `import MyClass from "./MyClass";`

Comment: @Doug is correct. Default exports need to be imported using the [default import syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults), e.g. `import MyClass from "./MyClass";` See [Has no exported member](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51331420/1715579)